# Birmingham, AL to Bombay (Roundtrip): Best route

Tags: air-travel, airlines, mumbai, alabama

This will be my first time going to Bombay via this route. Could anyone tell me if I should consider checking flights from Atlanta or BHM would be fine? Any travel agents to looks for or online websites would be my best bet to search for fares? I can see last two weeks of Dec fares rising up to $2000.

Comment: This is one of the busiest travel times of the year. Expect tickets to be expensive.

Comment: Have you looked on-line?  Kayak.com or Google Flights is the best place to start.

Answer (score 2):

(after a quick google and searching on flights aggregators)

Flying out from Birmingham will add at least an extra transfer at a major hub (atlanta, houston. newark...)

If you can make the drive to Atlanta (3 hours) , then you can reduce the number of transfers to 1 (mostly somewhere in Europe like Paris, Heathrow...).

At that time of the year prices will be a little bit higher than other time of year; but the earlier you can book, the cheaper it will be.

Good luck with that.

Comment: I was a bit surprised that you couldn't do something like BHM–(major US airport)–BOM;  but apparently the only non-stop service from BOM to anywhere in the US is to Newark, and there's no non-stop flight from Birmingham to Newark.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Some days there is a non-stop BHM-LGA but only 3h24m to get to EWR. Coming back is 5h which is more reasonable.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany given a choice between a two leg flight to Newark and a direct flight to LaGuardia plus a ground transfer to Newark, I'd be very strongly inclined to take the former.